# Automatically create Delphi/Freepascal interface unit from C header file

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, hdf5

Is it possible to automatically generate interface units from C header files? In particular, I want to wrap the HDF5 library, and it would be great if I could avoid writing the interface unit manually.

Comment: That looks like a very large and complex library. I will confidently predict that there is no tool that does a good and comprehensive translation.

Comment: There is a partial translation to Delphi of version 4 of the hdf library [here](http://dspatial.sourceforge.net/). You will find it under the `Drivers` folder. It may serve as a first step of translation.

Comment: Problem is HDF4 and HDF5 don't share anything except for the *HDF* in their name ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The free pascal includes the [H2PAS](http://www.freepascal.org/tools/h2pas.var) tool.

> **h2pas** attempts  to  convert  a  C header file to a pascal unit.  it can
>   handle most C constructs that one finds in a C  header  file,  and 
>   attempts to translate them to their pascal counterparts.

Comment: It is way better than other tools I used, but in practice you need to still do a lot of post processing by hand.

Answer (score 5):

Bob Swart ([Dr Bob](http://www.drbob42.com)) has a utility which will convert a lot of header files (although there's usually some manual work involved as well) called [HeaderConvert](http://www.drbob42.com/headconv/). I've never compared it to the tool @RRUZ links, but it's another option.

[Project JEDI](http://www.delphi-jedi.org) has one as well; I've never tested it. You can find it [here](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/api-howto.html).

Comment: The Jedi one is basically the same as headconv.

Answer (score 5):

In general **fully automated** translating of  C headers to something else (that isn't an effective superset of the needed C functionality) **is hard to impossible**.

This because due to macros one can't see how to translate them. Macros often only get their meaning from context. Example

```
#define uglymacro 1,2,3,4
```

but also (and this one is more common):

```
SCARYAPIMACRO void func(int c);
```

SCARYAPIMACRO is then often a macro that tests OS defines to select the right calling convention for the right OS/architecture.

Still, that doesn't mean that the tools are not real timesavers. But the result is more semiautomatic, I've the most and best experience with h2pas.

I've translated a lot of Windows headers (including FPC's commctrl which has a sendmessage macro every few lines).

What I usually do is craft a small pascal program that scans the source linebased and uses heuristics to split it into parts that are mostly homogeneous (all structs or constants,macros, procedure declaration etc). Then I look at the source and often do some global substitutes.

Only then I run it through the translator, the process is often iterative (refine separation, do global substitutions, try to translate, if it fails, try again etc).

The process unfortunately does require a good grasp of C, pragma stuff included.

Answer (score 1):

You can download HDF5 API header Delphi translations, Delphi XE2 HDF5 table test program with source code and somewhat modified hdf5dll from my page: 
http://www.astro.ff.vu.lt/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=46&Itemid=63